# assign every row a name with incremental integer to differentiate the rows in table in Vue.js

Tags: html, django, vue.js

I have a web app, front end is Vue.js, backend is Django.
I want to assign every row an name with increment integer to differ the rows in the table, so in the backend I could loop though an integer range to deal with them separately after form submitting.

```
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
                <form id="myform" method="post" action="/tag_course/">
            <table>
                <thead>
                ...
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(row, index) in Rows" :key="`isbn-${index}`">
<td :name="`title_${index}`" >{{ row.title }}</td>
                    <td :name="`discipline_code_course_code_${index}`"  bgcolor= "white"><div contenteditable></div></td>          

                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
<select id="semester" name="semester">
                    <option value="test">test</option>
                </select>

                </form>
    </div>
        <script>
          var book_rows = [{title:1, author:1, edition:1}, {title:2, author:2, edition:2}, {title:3, author:3, edition:3}]
            const app = new Vue({
                    el: '#app',
                    data:() => ({
                        filter: '',
                        rows: book_rows
                    }),
        });
        </script>
```

backend:

```
 def check(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)       #here I only got semester value, but no 
     title and discipline_code_course_code related value
```

I have around 1 thousand rows, how could I make name like Title_1, Title_2.... for the name attribute in different rows?

I have tried `:name="`title_${index}`"` as the name but failed. Backend no such key in post data

In the backend I could only got the normal name value(semester), but could not get the value using `:name="`discipline_code_course_code_${index}`or`:name="`title_${index}`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below

```
<td name="Title_{{index}}">{{ row.title }}</td>
```

or

```
<td :name="`Title_${index}`">{{ row.title }}</td>
```

Comment: failed using ur method, in the backend no related key in post, the post has nothing inside

Answer (score 0):

If I see it right you're already doing what you want to achieve! The combination of Isbn and the index you are using as key is the same you want to have for the name prop.

So you could just use

```
<td :name="`title_${index}`">{{ row.title }}</td>
```

By the way, it would be better to use something other than "isbn" and the index as the key. Maybe the real isbn if you have it, since it is unique.

Comment: Here is a good explanation why to use a unique key. Maybe in your case this will be no big impact but maybe in some time you implement switching the order of the books through your frontend where you can end up with some transition difficulties https://dev.to/mburazin/how-why-to-use-the-key-attribute-in-vuejs-v-for-loops-49f5

Comment: failed using ur method, in the backend no related key in post, the post has nothing inside

Comment: I think then you need to explain more detailed what you want to do. My answer provided you with a solution to name the generated <td /> tags by your v-for. If you want to add data in the front end to read it out in the backend you need to loop over it and add the specific property. Too help you out with that I need to see more code of yours to know what you want to achieve.